# When i select value from dropdown which is hardcoded it doesn't pick value and doesn't send it in database

Tags: php, html, css, angular, ionic4

My page.html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label color="medium">Leave</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="leavetype" name="leavetype">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let val of result" value=""> {{val. leavetype}} </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Example:-
I had values in dropdown list as given below:

```
Medical          
Casual              
Other
```

When I select 'casual' after closing the dropdown, it shows 'Medical' instead of 'Casual' and it doesn't save the value in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line to

```
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let val of result" value=""> {{val. leavetype}} </ion-select-option>
```

to

```
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let val of result" [value]="val.leavetype"> {{val. leavetype}} </ion-select-option>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: but it doesn't bind with ngmodel